# Including a background drawable foobars my layout in Android. Ideas why?

Tags: android, layout, background, android-linearlayout

If I don't include a background in my root layout then everything renders as I expect:

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/299320/correct.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/299320/correct.png)

However, if I add JUST ONE LINE adding in a background then the layout goes completely haywire:

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/299320/foobared.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/299320/foobared.png)

The relevant bit of the XML layout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width ="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingRight ="20dip" 
    android:paddingLeft  ="20dip"
    android:gravity      ="center_vertical"
    android:background   ="@drawable/main_background">
```

Quite literally the only difference between the above two screenshots is the inclusion of `android:background="@drawable/main_background"`. I'll give you a cookie if you can help me out here :)

Comment: For me, it seems that at runtime they look correct. The layout looks bad only in the designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As to why you are experiencing what you are with the background, it may be that your background image somehow gets caught up in the gravity, but that's just a guess.

As a workaround, wrap your whole thing in a `FrameLayout`. Make the first child of the `FrameLayout` be an `ImageView` with your background. Make the second child of the `FrameLayout` be your existing `LinearLayout` (sans `android:background`) attribute. Since `FrameLayout` and `RelativeLayout` allow stacking, this will cause your LinearLayout to appear above the image and should give you the visual effect you seek.

Comment: Man, that's annoying. I wish I had some inkling why what I was doing wasn't working. Your solution worked though, thanks.

Comment: I had a similar problem and spent a few hours wondering why. Never found out why Background images do that.